# How to parse XML in a string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string

Hi Fellow StackOverflowers,

I am receiving a string in one of my .NET function.  The string when viewed from the XML Visualizer looks like this:

```
- <root>
- <Table>
  <ID>ABC-123</ID>
  <CAT>Housekeeping</CAT>
  <DATE>21-JUN-2009</DATE>
  <REP_BY>John</REP_BY>
  <LOCATION>Head Office</LOCATION>
</Table>
- <Table>
  <ID>ABC-124</ID>
  <CAT>Environment</CAT>
  <DATE>23-JUN-2009</DATE>
  <REP_BY>Michelle</REP_BY>
  <LOCATION>Block C</LOCATION>
</Table>
- <Table>
  <ID>ABC-125</ID>
  <CAT>Staging</CAT>
  <DATE>21-JUN-2009</DATE>
  <REP_BY>George</REP_BY>
  <LOCATION>Head Office</LOCATION>
</Table>  
- <Table>
  <ID>ABC-123</ID>
  <CAT>Housekeeping</CAT>
  <DATE>21-JUN-2009</DATE>
  <REP_BY>John</REP_BY>
  <LOCATION space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" /> 
</Table>  
</root>
```

I need to parse this string so that I could write the data into a datatable whose columns are the xml tags for each data.

In the above text, I would then have a datatable that wil have 5 columns, named ID, CAT, DATE, REP_BY and LOCATION which will then contain 4 rows of data.

In the fourth  tag, notice that the  does not have any data, but rather it is marked space="preserve".  This would mean that the data I am placing in my datatable would be blank for the LOCATION column of the fourth row.

How can I achieve this? Sample codes would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming, you're using c#. What version do u use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the simplest solution to get the XML into table form. Throwing the attributes out using regular expressions is not that smart (and safe), but I don't like the `System.Xml` API and LINQ to XML is no option in .NET 2.0.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace GeneralTestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            String input = @"<root><Table> [...] </root>";

            input = Regex.Replace(input, @" [a-zA-Z]+=""[^""]*""", String.Empty);

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            dataSet.ReadXml(new StringReader(input));

            foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    Console.Write(row[column] + " | ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Or get rid of the attribute using `System.Xml`.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(new StringReader(input));

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("descendant-or-self::*"))
{
    node.Attributes.RemoveAll();
}

input = doc.OuterXml;
```

But this doesn't work because the XML namespace on the last `LOCATION` element remains and the `DataSet.LoadXml()` complains that there connot be two columns named `LOCATION`.

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote this answer.  Using a RegEx to clean the source string?  Even I, who hate using string processing on XML with a white-hot passion, might do that in this case.

Comment: I voted this as the answer since this has helped in particularly solving the case I got.

Answer (score 9):

Using the XmlReader class. This class is fast and does not use a lot of memory but reading the xml can be difficult.

```
using (StringReader strReader = new StringReader(yourXMLString))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strReader))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.Name == "Table" && reader.NodeType == reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                using(XmlReader tableReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    ReadTableNode(tableReader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ReadTableNode(XmlReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if(reader.Name == "ID" && reader.NodeType == reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            //do something
        else if(reader.Name == "CAT" && reader.NodeType == reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            //do something

       //and continue....
    }
}
```

To get an attribute of the current node you use:

```
string value = reader.GetAttribute(name_of_attribute);
```

To get the inner text of an element:

```
string innerText =  reader.ReadString();
```

Using the XmlDocument class. This class is slow but manipulating and reading the xml is very easy because the entire xml is loaded.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(yourXMLString);
//do something
```

Using the XDocument class. The advantage of using XDocument is elements can be accessed directly and simultaneously. This class also use the power of LINQ to query the xml document.

```
using(StringReader tr = new StringReader(yourXMLString))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);
    //do something
}
```

Comment: How would I then assemble the datatable's column names based on the data from the string?

Comment: Could you please provide more code example using the actual string data which I posted?

I tried your code but nothing comes up in my xmlreader variable.
Thanks.

Comment: I tried using the code you posted but nothing comes up in my string reader and xmlreader variables.  both have null values.

could you further elaborate? i am not getting anything in this statement:

    using (StringReader strReader = new StringReader(yourXMLString))

Comment: Did you replace the "yourXMLString" by your string?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string parsing. Try using some xml library ([Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) has some objects that might help you). You will probably do that much more easily.

Comment: Any other method aside from LINQ? I can't use LINQ since I am using .NET 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: oh, ok. Then Francis might be more helpful in your case. But I'm leaving it in case some .NET 3.5 finds this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can simply use the ADO.NET `DataSet` class's `ReadXml` method to read an XML document in that format, and it will create the `DataTable`, `DataColumn`, and `DataRow` objects for you.  You'll need to write a little conversion method if you want to subsequently turn the `DATE` column's data type to `DateTime`.  But other than that, you shouldn't have to screw around with XML at all.

**Edit**

I see from Daniel Bruckner's post that the LOCATION elements in the odd namespace pose a problem.  Well, that's easy enough to fix:

```
    XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
    d.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(d.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("n", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");
    foreach (XmlNode n in d.SelectNodes("/root/Table/n:LOCATION", ns))
    {
        XmlElement loc = d.CreateElement("LOCATION");
        n.ParentNode.AppendChild(loc);
        n.ParentNode.RemoveChild(n);
    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(d.OuterXml))
    {
        ds.ReadXml(sr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of xml myself, I need to use it as the datasource of a grid to visualize it.
I get some output from our FileNet imaging server in xml format and I need to get pieces of it out to populate a database.
Here's what I'm doing, HTH:

```
  Dim dsXML As DataSet
  Dim drXML As DataRow
  Dim rdr As System.IO.StringReader
  Dim docs() As String
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim xml As String
  Dim fnID As String

docs = _fnP8Dev.getDocumentsXML(_credToken, _docObjectStoreName, _docClass, "ReferenceNumber=" & fnID, "")
xml = docs(0)
If (InStr(xml, "<z:row") > 0) Then
 RaiseEvent msg("Inserting images for reference number " & fnID)
 rdr = New System.IO.StringReader(xml)
 dsXML = New DataSet
 dsXML.ReadXml(rdr)

 For Each drXML In dsXML.Tables(dsXML.Tables.Count - 1).Rows
   SQL = "Insert into fnImageP8 values ("
   SQL = SQL & "'" & drXML("Id") & "', "
   Try
    SQL = SQL & "'" & drXML("DocumentTitle") & "', "
   Catch ex As Exception
    SQL = SQL & "null, "
   End Try
```